# pyodbc always connects to master database

Tags: python, sql-server, odbc, azure-sql-database, pyodbc

I am using **pyodbc** to connect to an azure sql database. My source code looks like this:

```
import pyodbc

server = 'sqlserver.database.windows.net'
database = 'database'
username = 'username'
password = 'password'

conn= pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server}'+';SERVER='+server+';PORT=1443;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password ';Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("query")
```

I am able to connect to a sql database. The only thing which is not working properly is that pyodbc does not connect to the database I have specified in the `database` variable. It always connects to the master database.

What I have tried so far is to print the name of the databases on the target sql server using `SELECT * FROM sys.databases` while being connected to the master database. I was able to see the database I am trying to connect to. Anyone got an idea what goes wrong in my source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, I would assume that the connection string needs to be different in your case.
As per pyodbc docs:

> [...]the most important thing to remember is that pyodbc does not even look at the connection string. It is passed directly to the database driver unmodified (through SQLDriverConnect). Connection strings are therefore driver-specific and all ODBC connection string documentation should be valid.

https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connecting-to-databases

However, since you *are* connecting to db OK and your connection string seems to be ignored, I would say that if you are using Windows then the connection parameters seem likely to be defined in the ODBC DSN, which can be changed in Control panel. If that is the case, and you have ODBC parameters defined in DSN, most likely your connection string is ignored, except for  the choice of the DSN.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Very useful information. I tried to connect using a DSN entry and everything worked well. Still wondering though why the connection string didn&#39;t work. The connection string I used in the first attempt was leant on the connection string suggested in the azure portal. However the error messages in the first attempt (for example table not found) were clearly generated by the driver and not by pyodbc which conforms to your answer.

Comment: @0x51ba I think connection strings are a bit off course of the whole ODBC idea. The concept of DSNs is core odbc: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Database_Connectivity Technically as long as the correctly named ODBC DSN is present on the system, you should be able to migrate to another SQL server brand and your program wouldn't even notice.

Comment: @epattaro as far as I understand from ODBC docs, the parametrs passed to ODBC are not ignored *only* if the corresponding ODBC source did not have it. So if you want to pass uid & pwd to ODBC, you would have to have an ODBC source defined where uid and pwd are *not* set. Haven't tested it though.